# How accurate are Angus Maddisons historical GDP estimates?

Tags: economic-history, history

Angus Maddison estimates seem to be very often used by economic historians however they seem to be very speculatory.

This source states that they were unsure when the UK was surpassed in real GDP per capita by the USA, with proposed dates varying around 50 years.
https://www.joefrancis.info/known-unknowns/

Those two country are probably the most studied in the world, specially  regarding economics.

If Maddison estimates are so inaccurate why are they used by economics historians?

Link for Maddison Historical Statistics: https://www.rug.nl/ggdc/historicaldevelopment/maddison/?lang=en